# Problem to output a list in a function in python (leetcode)

Tags: python, list, function

I am facing a problem with the output function in leetcode. Usually the code I write is in a function and I don't understand how to give an output of a list because the return function doesn't work with a list. And using a print statement doesn't work as 'printing' doesn't go to 'Output' and goes to 'stdout'. Thank you
[image]

I tried both printing and returning the list I want as an output. I got a result online but I don't understand the code, can anyone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include your code as Text and not as an image.  As for returning a list,  can you please clarify what you mean.  Do you mean ```return nums``` or is it something else?

Comment: I think you just need to return the new element count.  The caller already has the list, and I expect it will check it on its own.  So I wouldn't worry about printing or returning the final list.  I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: The question asks you to return the length of the modified list - not a reference to the list itself. Also, the list has to be modified *in situ*

Answer (score 0):

You can return lists like so:

```py
def foo(x):
    # Or (1,2) or [1,["a",2]] etc
    return [1,2]
```

You are trying to return `j + 1`; which is not a list

---

Do you want to `return nums`?

Comment: This doesn't address the question.